# Cross account Cloudformation macro

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I am trying to create a cross account macro which will will be used in Cloudformation.
According to the doc - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html we have to create macros in different accounts but the underlying lambda can be re-used by making it cross account accessible.

**Sample Example:**

#Account A#
In Account_A(2
22222222222) I have created a lambda function "TestMacroFunction" which is used in the macro.

I have added following trust policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com",
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam:: 22222222222:role/service-role/TestLambdaInvoker-role-lu7aa94t"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

## Account B#

In Account_B(111111111111) which will have a cloudformation stack for Macro and another stack which will use the macro.

CFN for macro

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Resources": {
    "SageMakerEndpointAlarmsMacro": {
      "Type": "AWS::CloudFormation::Macro",
      "Properties": {
        "Name": "ExternalMacro",
        "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:111111111111:function:TestMacroFunction",
        "LogGroupName": "MacroLogGroup"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

CFN for Stack using macro:

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Transform": [
    "ExternalMacro"
  ],
  "Resources": {
    "TestBucket": {
      "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
      "Properties": {}
    }
  }
}
```

While running the CFN stack I provide a Role which has following policy attached:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "lambda:InvokeFunction"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:111111111111:function:TestMacroFunction",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

But still I am getting error in cloudformation. The transform in not executing. Also the lambda function is not getting invoked.

Has anyone created a lambda which is used by macros in other account?

Comment: I have never used cross-account macros. However, I believe you may also need to add permission to the Lambda function to be invoked by the CloudFormation in another account. This is the CloudFormation resource: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-permission.html. It needs to be added to the Lambda function created in account A - 22222222222.

Answer (score 0):

Your post is full of errors:

- The IAM role ARN you list under Account A has `483427547108` as the accountId even though you say that Account A should have the accountId `22222222222` in your example.
- The Lambda function ARN you put as the target of Account B's macro is supposed to be in Account A, right? But with the accountId you used, it's under account B.
- Why are you using `22222222222` for Account A and `111111111111` for Account B?  This makes your question unnecessarily confusing, and it seems like you managed to confuse yourself as well given the mistakes in your post.

Anyway, here's the answer:

So when the Lambda function (in Account A) is invoked, it will look like it's coming from Account B.  In order for this to work, you need to **add permission to your Lambda function** (in Account A) that allows Account B to call it.  It should look something like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "default",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "test",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:root"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:22222222222:function:TestMacroFunction"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can do this in the Lambda console by opening up your Lambda function, clicking the Configuration tab, clicking the Permissions sub-tab, then clicking "Add permissions".  In the next screen, select `AWS account`, then enter any string for the Statement ID, then enter your account like `arn:aws:iam::111111111111:root` for the Principal, then select `lambda:InvokeFunction` for the Action.  Click "Save" and you should be good to go.